# use user input and return smallest and biggest number - excersise coursera Python

Tags: python-3.x, logic

Im working on this now for over an hour and cant figure why the result is Maximum 7 and minimum 10.. Something is wrong with my logic here. I know there are other ways of solving this but I only want to use the things that were tought in the course.

```
largest = None
smallest = None
while True:
    num = input("Enter a number: ")
    if num == "done":
        break
    try:
        int(num)
    except:
        print("Invalid input")
        continue
    if largest is None:
        largest = num
    elif num > largest:
        largest = num
    if smallest is None:
        smallest = num
    elif num < smallest:
        smallest = num

print("Maximum", largest)
print("Minimum", smallest)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to save the input into a variable as an Integer (num = int(Number)

```
largest = None
smallest = None
while True:
    Number = input("Enter a number: ")
    if Number == "done":
        break
    try:
        int(Number)
    except:
        print("Invalid input")
        continue
    num = int(Number)
    if largest is None:
        largest = num
    elif num > largest:
        largest = num
    if smallest is None:
        smallest = num
    if num < smallest:
        smallest = num

print("Maximum", largest)
print("Minimum", smallest)
```